# Powershell script to create calculated field in Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a calculated column in a Sharepoint list using this formula.

=CONCATENATE("<a href='https://apps.powerapps.com/play/qqq?FieldID=",[Field Number],">",Title,"")

How do I create a field like this using Pnp.  I've tried this, but it fails.

```
 Add-PnPField -List $ListName -DisplayName 'PowerAppLink' -InternalName PowerAppLink -Type Calculated -Formula "CONCATENATE(`"`<a href='https://apps.powerapps.com/play/qqq?CABID=",[CAB Number],"`>`",Title,"`</a`>")" -AddToDefaultView
```

The error message is
Error adding field: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Formula'. Specified method is not supported.

I think that instead of using  Add-PnPField, I need to use  Add-PnPFieldFromXml as this allows me to specify the output of the calculated field as text.  Still struggling with the syntax.

Comment: "I've tried this, but it fails." - how did it fail? Did it create a field with the wrong expression? If so, what was the resulting expression? Did it fail with an error? If so, what was the error message? Please be mindful that we can't see your screen, only you can :)

Comment: I've edited the question to include the error message.  There are rows above and below this row which work successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.  $FormulaPowerappLink = "=CONCATENATE("<a href='https://apps.powerapps.com/play/ccc?CABID=",[CAB Number],">",[Title],"</a>")"

Need to escape the quotes and angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a verbatim string literal (`'` instead of `"`) - then the only characters you need to escape are `'`:

```
$expression = 'CONCATENATE("<a href=''https://apps.powerapps.com/play/qqq?CABID=",[CAB Number],"''>",Title,"</a>")'

Add-PnPField -List $ListName -DisplayName 'PowerAppLink' -InternalName PowerAppLink -Type Calculated -Formula $expression -AddToDefaultView
```

Comment: @AlHal Perhaps `Title` needs to be surrounded by braces too? eg. `[Title]`

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the Calculated column formula is correct. You can create a Calculated column in the list through SharePoint UI to see if the formula works normally.

Eg:

**Formula:**

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href=''https://apps.powerapps.com/play/qqq?CABID=",[CAB Number],"''>",[Title],"</a>")
```

[image]

[image]

Then, please run the below PNP Powershell as an admin

```
$SiteURL = "https://echodu.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite1"

$ListName= "ListD"
  
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

$ex = '=CONCATENATE("<a href=''https://apps.powerapps.com/play/qqq?CABID=",[CAB Number],"''>",[Title],"</a>")'

Add-PnPField -List $ListName -Type Calculated -InternalName "PowerAppLink" -DisplayName "PowerAppLink" -Formula $ex -AddToDefaultView
```

[image]

Comment: It creates the field, but when I manually enter a row into the list, the Powerapp link field remains blank.  I have another field whose display name is CAB Number and whose internal ID is CabNumber.